# How could new WaitHandle [] return null? Or does it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle, fluorinefx, prtg

I am using a **FluorineFx 1.0.0.17** in my project and working with `NetConnection` to connect to a RTMP host (Flash Media Server). I am creating a RTMP monitoring probe for PRTG.

There is always an error **at the end of the main application process** on the line 173 of `WorkItemsQueue.cs` file (second code line shown here)

```
// Prepare array of wait handle for the WaitHandle.WaitAny()
WaitHandle [] waitHandles = new WaitHandle [] { WaitEntry.WaitHandle, cancelEvent };

// Wait for available resource, cancel event, or timeout.
int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles, millisecondsTimeout, true);
```

This is what debugger shows me:

[image]

Call stack:

```
[In a sleep, wait, or join] 
[External Code] 
FluorineFx.dll!FluorineFx.Threading.WorkItemsQueue.DequeueWorkItem(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.WaitHandle cancelEvent) Line 173 + 0xd bytes   C#
FluorineFx.dll!FluorineFx.Threading.ThreadPoolEx.Dequeue() Line 329 + 0x2c bytes    C#
FluorineFx.dll!FluorineFx.Threading.ThreadPoolEx.ProcessQueuedItems() Line 378 + 0x8 bytes  C#
[External Code] 
kernel32.dll!749c3677()     
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]  
ntdll.dll!770e9f42()    
ntdll.dll!770e9f15()
```

By *at the end of the process* I mean whole program works as it should, but when at the end of Main method debugger throws this unmanaged-code error (shows only if *Enable unmanaged code debugging* is enabled).

[image]

**I have no idea how to debug this, nor how to avoid it. Any help would be appreciated.**

UPDATE 1:

[image]

Main threads stopps at:

```
 Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Btw, your call stack is for the wrong thread. IOW not one throwing the exception.

Comment: @leppie It is heap corruption. Debugging will not show correct result.

Comment: @Aliostad: Heap corruption is a rather vague 'reason'. (perhaps I am ignorant common from a pure managed world ;p)

Comment: @leppie It is access violation, i.e. process attempted to access a memory location not within its memory space. This happens with buffer overruns, ... you name it.

Comment: @Aliostad: Ahh, I see now. Subtle differences in the messages of the same error code. :)

Comment: @mizi_sk: Try adding a null entry at the end of the array. (just a hunch)

Comment: @leppie ;) I have done some unmanaged C, C++ and used in .NET and familiar with its pains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio could be lying to you in case of Multi-Threaded debugging. It is **not** possible for the `waitHandles` to be `null`.

You seem to have a **corrupted heap**.

## Detail

You get access violation when process attempted to access a memory location not within its memory space. This happens with buffer overruns, ... you name it. If you use an unmanaged code, this could easily do it.

Comment: What should I do then? How to debug it? I would gladly just hack the error out, as it is after the program ends.

Comment: Your heap is corrupt. Something in the unmanaged code is corrupting your heap. Finding that out is **not easy**.

Comment: I am using FluorineFx library and my code is like 20 lines. So it seems I should contact FluorineFx support. (I am adding a threads debug screenshot)

Comment: Yes, I would say if you have paid for it, you do. It might need some cleanup code before it finishes so that is what you are missing.

Comment: Thanks @Aliostad however FluorineFx support is little slow (whole FluorineFx is one man side job as I understand it) so I will look into alternative RTMP C# client libraries.

Comment: Old good truth says: "Want something done right? Do it yourself."